# Query random documents from a Solr database

Tags: solr

Is it possible to execute a query that returns a random selection of *n* documents from a very large Solr database? I do not wish to randomly sort results of a premade query, but rather just pull random documents from the entire database.

Comment: https://solr.pl/en/2013/04/02/random-documents-from-result-set-giveaway-results/

Answer (score 0):

If you sort=random_ with a rows= will do what you want - get you random docs - but it will create a random number per doc - so you should should test with a large document set

Br
Klaus